# IE 11 not applying ellipsis on element

Tags: css, reactjs, internet-explorer

I have an element in a grid that applies the truncation '...' in every browser but IE11.

The initial styling for the element is

```
max-width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis:
white-space: nowrap;
```

I have tried adding -ms-text-overflow, word-wrap and display: block to no avail, as well as adding readonly on the element in question.

How can I get IE to apply the truncation correctly?

Comment: Does anyone still using IE?

Comment: @delmin unfortunately yes they do. But on the positive side it is declining rapidly from last year, based on metrics I seen in clients data.

Comment: @Dejan.S I thought that dinosaur is already extinct.

Comment: @delmin yea I wish it was! We don't go the extra mile to make everything look the same in IE11, functions yes but not visuals.

Comment: @Dejan.S I’m displaying ‘Not supported for IE’ nicely cetered in the middle of the screen.. Obviously not a perfect solution for all website but it definitely help to kill it

Comment: @delmin, IE11 even more than Firefox worldwide (8% vs. 5.1%) of a total of 4.33 billion people online. Actually you will be dismissing well over 346 million people. A lot of companies running on Windows enforce using IE11/Edge. Just so you know...

Comment: @RenevanderLende yeah as I said not a perfect solution for all web sites but in most of them I'm applying this... Matter of fact most businesses have also other web browser installed in their old pcs which will force them to use other browsers.

Comment: @RenevanderLende well that number is not accurate. Firefox is 9.36%, IE is 3.95%. Also the number about people is not valid and kinda don't make sense. Not all 4 billion people have computers. You have to look to each individual site and look at the metrics and see if it make sense to support older browsers or not. My current client has has 1% IE11 usage but generates revenue, so support yes, but % has declined 4% from last year... All about the specific site metrics.

Comment: Hi GoldCasket, you might not realize, but the accepted answer (still) fails. It shows dots because there are dots in the text, but no ellipsis when it should (at all). Change the dots to some text and you can see for yourself. I have asked the OP of the answer to correct this, but sofar he did not comply. Please accept another **correct** answer as a question on SO with a faulty answer is bad. (e.g. I showed you two solutions that run on IE11 too).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this workaround on your class where you want your ellipsis:

```
.ellipsis-stuff {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.ellipsis-stuff:before {
  content: ''; /* IE9 ellipsis fix */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fokjuLhp/9/

Comment: I'll give it a go, but any reason for a set width on max-width here?

Comment: No reason other for easier construction of an example. Now if my <p> tag exceeds 300px, it will overflow, triggering the ellipsis

Comment: Not sure how you tested the Fiddle on IE11, but all the dots in the  `<p>` obfuscate the fact that your solution does not show an 'ellipsis' in any browser. You need to change `.ellipsis-stuff` to `.ellipsis-stuff>*` and it will work in IE11, even without the `:before` rule.

Comment: I see, what a silly mistake. I will update my fiddle

Answer (score 0):

In most cases an 'ellipsis' will only be shown when an element has a (max-)width set ('hard limit' in fixed units). All three properties are mandatory for the ellipsis to work. This works without extra modifications in IE11 too.

Try the following two situations:

1. first `.single, .multiple { width: 100% }` and resize the browser: no ellipsis
2. then `body { max-width: 100px } .single, .multiple { width: 100% }`: ellipsis again

Hence, you need some 'hard limit'.

```css
.single,
.multiple { width: 100px } /* or max-width */

.single,
.multiple>* {
  white-space: nowrap;     /* [MANDATORY] */
  overflow: hidden;        /* [MANDATORY] */
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* [MANDATORY] */
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="single">this is single element</div>
<div class="multiple">
    <p>this is multiple 1</p>
    <p>this is multiple 2</p>
    <p>this is multiple 3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what kind of style applied to your grid and on which element you are trying to apply the ellipsis.

I make a test with this sample code and it is working with the IE 11 browser.

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

div.b {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 50px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="b">Hello world!</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Output with the IE 11 browser:

[image]

You can try to apply this code to your original code and see whether helps to fix the issue.

If the issue persists then please try to provide the sample code that can produce the issue with the IE 11 browser. We will try to check and test it and try to provide the suggestions for it.